# laravel 5.3 md5_file... failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, permission-denied, laravel-5.3

Hello I'm using Laravel 5.3 on Xampp (dev mode) and AWS (production mode) and I have a problem with pdf File upload . My post and edit function are working for some pdf uploads but not all of them ! For pdf I created and uploaded (under 2Mo), the upload is working but for the others I have an error page with this info :

```
ErrorException in FileHelpers.php line 49:
md5_file(C:\xampp\htdocs\sol\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied

    in FileHelpers.php line 49
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'md5_file(C:\xampp\htdocs\sol\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sol\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\FileHelpers.php', '49', array('path' => null))
at md5_file('C:\xampp\htdocs\sol\public') in FileHelpers.php line 49
at UploadedFile->hashName() in UploadedFile.php line 23
at UploadedFile->store('5_2_manuals') in ManualController.php line 72
at ManualController->store(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ManualController), 'store'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('store', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(ManualController), 'store') in Route.php line 190
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 642
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 43
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\sol\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

I did look at the permissions and change it with : chmod -R 777 storage, it didn't change anything.

Thanks for your help

Comment: try to run xampp as administrator. cuz mostly windows 7 requires permission when handling files in C drive

Comment: Thanks, I do have same problem on aws my production server. Is there anything I can modify ?

Comment: In production it can be problem with configuration of php.ini, sometimes open_basedir attribute prevents to access some path

Comment: but look, You did: chmod -R 777 storage, but in exception problem is with public folder, try this: chmod -R 0755 public

Comment: I did try with the chmod -R755 public, it didn't change anything. still the same message : "(ErrorException in FileHelpers.php line 49:
md5_file(C:\xampp\htdocs\sol\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Comment: Fabrice! You're using Windows! Is there any command like: chmod? :)  also check: chmod -R 0755 public   (see spaces and exact path from relative folder)

Comment: Thanks numb8r I'm used to OS X... It does work now : I had an error with Upload_max_filesize, Post_max_size, too low as well